# VIM refresh screen or fix rendering

Tags: vim

When I ssh into an account for hosted website and use vim to edit files; I see strange behavior.

- Let's create file with one number (01 to 25) on each line.
- Change line 15 from "15" to "15 15 15 15"
- Change the size of xterm window so that only 10 lines are visible.
- Position cursor on first line of file.
- Press PgDn then PgUp.
- On line "07" I see "07 15 15 15" yet only "07" is really in the file!
- If I use up/down arrow to move many lines away and then back again; everything is fine; but this is annoying.

1. Is there a command that will "refresh" the vim screen?
2. is there a command line option to "fix" this behaviour?
3. Is there a way to permanetnly fix this behaviour for my account on this remote system?

Comment: 1. `Ctrl+L` in Normal mode. 2. [`:redraw`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:redraw) in vim command line.

Comment: @phd - both of these suggestions have no affect.

Comment: Even `:redraw!` with exclamation mark?

Comment: Same - no effect.

Comment: Broken terminal description. `echo $TERM`, compare terminal description with your local using [`infocmp`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/infocmp) and so on. But that's offtopic for SO as SO is a site for programming questions. You probably need https://askubuntu.com/ , https://serverfault.com/ , https://superuser.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/